# Android GridView garbage collecting (GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC) <1K overzealously, causing very choppy UI

Tags: android, gridview, garbage-collection, scroll

I have been looking at this for a long time and finally decided to post - my 2xN GridView, which consists of cells with a single image and piece of text is very choppy a lot of times (but sometimes perfectly smooth). Upon examining logcat output, I see things like this once I start scrolling (there are only 12 items in the list):

```
10-25 17:28:40.420: D/dalvikvm(12159): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 6K, 47% free 3383K/6279K, external 2044K/2161K, paused 38ms
10-25 17:28:40.510: D/dalvikvm(12159): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 3383K/6279K, external 2044K/2161K, paused 36ms
10-25 17:28:40.600: D/dalvikvm(12159): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 3383K/6279K, external 2044K/2161K, paused 40ms
10-25 17:28:41.805: D/dalvikvm(12159): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 47% free 3383K/6279K, external 2044K/2161K, paused 34ms
10-25 17:28:41.840: D/dalvikvm(12159): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 3383K/6279K, external 2044K/2161K, paused 25ms
10-25 17:28:41.880: D/dalvikvm(12159): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 3383K/6279K, external 2044K/2161K, paused 25ms
10-25 17:28:41.910: D/dalvikvm(12159): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 3383K/6279K, external 2044K/2161K, paused 20ms
10-25 17:28:41.940: D/dalvikvm(12159): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 3383K/6279K, external 2044K/2161K, paused 18ms
```

This was only a single flick to the bottom of the list and back up. Very choppy. If I keep scrolling up and down, the GC keeps going for maybe 5-6 scrolls, then stops. But as soon as I press Menu which brings up a 2-entry menu or switch activities and come back, GC comes back too.

I turned off bitmap assignments for the image - same problem. My cells are essentially empty, yet GC still happens.

I contacted Romain Guy who said I should try allocation tracking. I ran tracking and flicked, but saw no allocation in my own code. I did see allocations followed by calls to 
com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher allocated in finalize, which matches the number of GC lines in logcat. Here is the whole Allocation Tracker dump (or [as a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH8mO.png) which is easier to parse):

```
1   24  org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.Chunk    5   org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer    dispatch    
2   12  java.lang.Integer   5   java.lang.Integer   valueOf 
3   24  byte[]  5   dalvik.system.NativeStart   run 
4   20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
5   20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
6   20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
7   20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
8   20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
9   20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
10  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
11  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
12  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
13  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
14  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
15  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
16  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
17  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
18  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
19  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
20  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
21  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
22  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
23  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
24  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
25  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
26  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
27  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
28  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
29  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
30  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
31  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
32  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
33  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
34  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
35  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
36  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
37  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
38  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
39  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
40  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
41  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
42  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
43  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
44  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
45  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
46  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
47  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
48  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
49  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
50  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
51  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
52  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
53  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
54  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
55  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
56  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
57  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
58  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
59  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
60  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
61  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
62  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
63  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
64  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
65  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
66  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
67  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
68  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
69  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
70  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
71  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
72  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
73  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
74  24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
75  36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
76  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
77  24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
78  36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
79  24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
80  36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
81  8   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
82  24  java.lang.ref.WeakReference 2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
83  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
84  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
85  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
86  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
87  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
88  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
89  24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
90  36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
91  24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
92  36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
93  20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
94  24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
95  36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
96  8   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
97  24  java.lang.ref.WeakReference 2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
98  24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
99  36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
100 20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
101 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
102 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
103 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
104 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
105 8   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
106 24  java.lang.ref.WeakReference 2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
107 20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
108 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
109 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
110 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
111 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
112 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
113 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
114 8   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
115 24  java.lang.ref.WeakReference 2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
116 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
117 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
118 20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
119 60  com.carrieriq.iqagent.client.metrics.ui.UI11    1   android.view.ViewRoot   submitPointerMetrics    
120 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
121 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
122 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
123 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
124 8   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
125 24  java.lang.ref.WeakReference 2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
126 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
127 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
128 20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
129 60  com.carrieriq.iqagent.client.metrics.ui.UI11    1   android.view.ViewRoot   submitPointerMetrics    
130 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
131 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
132 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
133 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
134 8   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
135 24  java.lang.ref.WeakReference 2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
136 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
137 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
138 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
139 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
140 20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
141 60  com.carrieriq.iqagent.client.metrics.ui.UI11    1   android.view.ViewRoot   submitPointerMetrics    
142 60  com.carrieriq.iqagent.client.metrics.ui.UI11    1   android.view.ViewRoot   submitPointerMetrics    
143 60  com.carrieriq.iqagent.client.metrics.ui.UI11    1   android.view.ViewRoot   submitPointerMetrics    
144 20  java.util.ArrayList 19  android.os.MessageQueue <init>  
145 36  android.os.MessageQueue 19  android.os.Looper   <init>  
146 24  android.os.Looper   19  android.os.Looper   prepare 
147 144 java.lang.Object[]  19  java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values    initializeTable 
148 32  java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values    19  java.lang.ThreadLocal   initializeValues    
149 16  java.lang.VMThread  1   java.lang.VMThread  create  
150 40  java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry 1   java.util.WeakHashMap   put 
151 16  java.security.ProtectionDomain[]    1   java.security.AccessControlContext  <init>  
152 20  java.security.AccessControlContext  1   java.security.AccessController  getContext  
153 16  java.security.ProtectionDomain[]    1   java.security.AccessController  getStackDomains 
154 24  java.lang.String    1   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder toString    
155 48  char[]  1   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder <init>  
156 20  java.lang.StringBuilder 1   java.lang.Thread    create  
157 16  android.view.ViewRoot$2 1   android.view.ViewRoot   handleLongPress 
158 80  java.lang.Thread    1   android.view.ViewRoot   handleLongPress 
159 60  com.carrieriq.iqagent.client.metrics.ui.UI11    1   android.view.ViewRoot   submitPointerMetrics    
160 24  org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.Chunk    5   android.ddm.DdmHandleHeap   handleREAQ  
161 17  byte[]  5   android.ddm.DdmHandleHeap   handleREAQ  
162 24  org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.Chunk    5   org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer    dispatch    
163 12  java.lang.Integer   5   java.lang.Integer   valueOf 
164 24  byte[]  5   dalvik.system.NativeStart   run
```

As you can see, the events directly preceding GC and happening in between every GC, are pretty much as follows:

```
107 20  java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$ListIteratorImpl  1   java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    
108 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
109 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
110 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
111 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
112 24  java.lang.ref.SoftReference 1   android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   
113 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
114 8   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize    
115 24  java.lang.ref.WeakReference 2   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher    finalize
```

I really wish the allocation tracker let me export the whole dump with individual stack traces, but it doesn't, so I'll paste a few stack traces here, most of which have to do with drawing:

android.graphics.Bitmap:

```
android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    Bitmap.java -2  true    
android.graphics.Bitmap createBitmap    Bitmap.java 477 false   
android.view.View   buildDrawingCache   View.java   6716    false   
android.view.View   getDrawingCache View.java   6567    false   
android.view.ViewGroup  drawChild   ViewGroup.java  1571    false   
android.view.ViewGroup  dispatchDraw    ViewGroup.java  1373    false   
android.widget.AbsListView  dispatchDraw    AbsListView.java    1627    false   
android.widget.GridView dispatchDraw    GridView.java   1943    false   
android.view.View   draw    View.java   7022    false   
android.widget.AbsListView  draw    AbsListView.java    3005    false   
android.view.ViewGroup  drawChild   ViewGroup.java  1646    false   
android.view.ViewGroup  dispatchDraw    ViewGroup.java  1373    false   
android.view.View   draw    View.java   7022    false   
android.view.ViewGroup  drawChild   ViewGroup.java  1646    false   
android.view.ViewGroup  dispatchDraw    ViewGroup.java  1373    false   
android.view.ViewGroup  drawChild   ViewGroup.java  1644    false
```

java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList:

```
java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList   iterator    CopyOnWriteArrayList.java   332 false   
android.view.ViewTreeObserver   dispatchOnPreDraw   ViewTreeObserver.java   570 false   
android.view.ViewRoot   performTraversals   ViewRoot.java   1293    false   
android.view.ViewRoot   handleMessage   ViewRoot.java   1899    false   
android.os.Handler  dispatchMessage Handler.java    99  false   
android.os.Looper   loop    Looper.java 130 false   
android.app.ActivityThread  main    ActivityThread.java 3691    false   
java.lang.reflect.Method    invokeNative    Method.java -2  true    
java.lang.reflect.Method    invoke  Method.java 507 false   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller  run ZygoteInit.java 907 false   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit  main    ZygoteInit.java 665 false   
dalvik.system.NativeStart   main    NativeStart.java    -2  true
```

Here is my GridView container XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/scroll_items_holder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <GridView
      android:id="@+id/gridview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:columnWidth="150dp"
      android:gravity="right"
      android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
      android:listSelector="@null"
      android:numColumns="auto_fit"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
      android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <include layout="@layout/menu_bar_inc" />
</LinearLayout>
```

XML file for each GridView cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/card"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/show_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter, most of which is commented out:

```
package com.tunerfish.tunerfish.adapters;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.tunerfish.tunerfish.core.TfHomeActivity;
import com.tunerfish.tunerfish.databasemanager.dataitem.EntityDataItem;
import com.tunerfish.tunerfish.ui.R;

public class TrendingGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  // structure for dumb view holders
  public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView showName;
    // public ImageViewWithLoader thumbnail;
  }

  // structure for actual data behind the ListView
  public static class EntityData {
    public EntityDataItem entityDataItem;
  }

  public final ArrayList<EntityData> mEntityDataList;

  private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

  public TrendingGalleryAdapter(TfHomeActivity context, ArrayList<EntityData> entityData) {
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mEntityDataList = entityData;
  }

  @Override public int getCount() {
    return mEntityDataList.size();
  }

  @Override public EntityData getItem(int position) {
    return mEntityDataList.get(position);
  }

  @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  private final TfHomeActivity mContext;

  @Override public View getView(final int position, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (inView == null) {
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      inView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.trending_item_mod, null);
      holder.showName = (TextView) inView.findViewById(R.id.show_name);
      // holder.thumbnail = (ImageViewWithLoader) inView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

      inView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) inView.getTag();
    }

    // reset some stuff
    // holder.thumbnail.getImageView().setImageBitmap(null);

    // holder.showName.setText(getItem(position).entityDataItem.getTitle());

    // deal with thumbnails
    String thumbnailUrl = getItem(position).entityDataItem.getTrendingThumbnail();
    // mContext.sendImgDownloadRequest(thumbnailUrl, holder.thumbnail.getImageView(), R.drawable.tunerfish_details_logo2);

    return inView;
  }
}
```

So, this question may look long, but I wanted to include as much info as possible. I found a possibly related ListView issue [Lots of garbage collection in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977718/lots-of-garbage-collection-in-a-listview) but unfortunately it doesn't seem to apply to GridViews.

Additionally, it doesn't seem like I'm alone with this problem - a friend of mine contacted me to ask about exactly the same issue in his app, completely independently.

My test devices are OG Droid running CM 7.1 and Epic 4G Touch running stock Gingerbread.

So is this a framework bug? Am I doing something wrong? Am I not including a certain parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you making sure to use the convertView parameter in your getView method in your adapter class?

Comment: The code is right above - you can see it yourself. I believe getView is implemented correctly but it's not related to the problem. See my answer below.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I should've read closer. My bad.

Comment: Ummm... are you downloading the images each time that `getView()` is called (the `sendImgDownloadRequest`)? If so, that's why your `ListView` is choppy! You're doing network requests in the UI thread! Use asynctasks and cache the images.

Comment: @dmon The code figures out if the image is in cache and uses cache in that case. It doesn't download every time. Furthermore, I put a scroll listener and hold all download requests until the scrolling stops to optimize scrolling further.

Comment: One thing Romain Guy is right about - my GridView should not use wrap_content, as that will apparently cause multiple calls to getView().

Comment: When you say "is in cache", is that an in-memory or on-storage cache? Also, why are you using a ViewHolder and not pulling information directly from the Views children? Also, have you looked at the Shelves project (http://code.google.com/p/shelves/) which has some tricks to improve the handling of flick scrolling.

Comment: For starters, optimize the layouts.  match_parent on your GridView's height is a good start.  I also don't see any reason for the outermost LinearLayout in the container XML file.  Fixing those won't directly solve the problem, but they'll help.  Also you say "I turned off bitmap assignments for the image - same problem."  Is the GC still external that's causing the lag in that case?

Comment: Also, for the sake of eliminating some possibilities, have you tried specifying an exact height for the GridView items?

Comment: @Al in-memory Bitmap cache. I'm not sure what you mean by pulling information from Views children. Haven't looked at shelves, thanks. The problem seems to go away though with the below scrollingCache solution, FWIW.

Comment: @Ian There is an <include> you probably missed in the container XML, at the end. I'll switch to match_parent (aka fill_parent) and see how it affects things. GC is still external when bitmaps are turned off - in fact, they were turned off when I posted this question. I haven't tried specifying exact height, I can try that too.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii You're right, I missed the include.  As a minor note, your Adapter could extend ArrayAdapter.  Shoot me an email after you've tried an exact height for the cells.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After trying out more things at random, I believe I was able to solve the issue by setting GridView's `scrollingCache` to `false` in the XML. It's now buttery smooth.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:scrollingCache

So, a setting that is supposed to make the GridView use more memory and draw from cache faster in fact causes just the opposite due to GC by making it choppy. Turning the cache off uses less memory and isn't choppy anymore.

This is a win-win in my book, and I hope it helps someone in the future (ಠ_ಠ Google).

**Edit**: Just tried it on a decently-performing ListView, which occasionally would call GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC to free small amounts of memory. Removing it from a ListView got rid of many tiny GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC calls altogether and only an occasional larger GC_CONCURRENT call is left. Now a decently-performing ListView is a great-performing ListView. So `scrollingCache` seems to be something to avoid in any list and shouldn't be enabled by default IMO.

Comment: Using more memory will in general lead to more garbage collections. This is especially true of Android 2.3+ where GC is more incremental, but theoretically less obtrusive.

Comment: Exactly, so scrollCaching seems to be something to avoid in any list. Removing it from a ListView got rid of many tiny GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC calls altogether and only an occasional larger GC_CONCURRENT call is left.

Comment: Please don't make generic assertions like this without truly understanding what might be going on. If scrollingCache was a generic issue, we would not leave it on by default. Your particular problem is likely due to your list items varying size. Whenever a cached view is resized, its bitmap cache needs to be recreated, which is *not* the common case.

Comment: My GridView doesn't vary in size - it's a single line of text + single image with a predefined height. As for ListViews, I would argue that cells of varying heights in ListView are common, most of the time due to things like titles that can overflow to more than 1 line.

Comment: Either way, I'm not alone in having this problem, and I would love to see some sort of explanations, discussions, advisories in guides and API docs. There's a *serious* performance implication here, and it couldn't hurt to make it known to developers that this is where the issue might lie, even if it doesn't happen in every case.

Comment: I'll add my voice here. I tested this on Android 2.3.4 and came up with the same results as Artem.  When scrollcache is enabled on a gridview or listview, there is lots of garbage collector activity and performance is choppy.  When disabled, the GC goes quiet and the performance is smooth.

Comment: @BitBank Thank you for another confirmation.

Comment: @RomainGuy Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @RomainGuy: what happened? Did you get anything?

Comment: this also fixed a concurrency timeout error I had when flinging a gridview around...weird...

Answer (score 2):

This is also a problem with ListViews, and the frequent stop-the-world garbage collection causes a poor end-user experience and leads the user to blame Android for choppy UI performance. However, this problem can also be solved in the same way by setting the `scrollingCache` to false.

Answer (score 1):

Using SimpleCursorAdapter with a custom 2 line ListView layout being used in a ListActivity, no images just text and I have CacheColorHint - #00000000.
before I begin I will say that a quick fix is removing cachecolorhint but I need it so it is not a fix to the GC so....

I have had issues with this same problem now and in the past however this throws a curve ball in it...  I have two applications which are essentially mirror images of each other.  One will run just fine with no rampant Garbage Collection in the logcat and it scrolls beautifully, The other does not work so well and nothing, no copy and pasting of code can fix it from one to the other.

ALSO!...Sometimes in the app that is not working so well, I can get it to work when I resort the list from a query and use a slightly different layout for the list view.  Don't jump to conclusions though because if I navigate away and come back, the same sorted query using simple cursor adapter on a custom 2 line list item layout will cause the GC again.  In other words sometimes it will simply work correctly, and other times it won't.  Mind you, I have "scrollingCache" left as the default on both apps and as I said they are copies of each other.

A while back I encountered this and was able to resolve it somehow and it had nothing to do with ScrollingCache.  Rather it had to do with my build compiling against some old version of Android (I think)  My memory is not 100% certain of this but I swear the fix was related to a build/compiler issue.  I will post something if I remember what fixed it.  I use Surround so I am searching for changes.
I hope this made sense