# GridView (calendar) performance issue (+70 getView calls, GC_FOR_ALLOC, UI freezes)

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-adapter

I'm trying to build a monthly calendar in my Android Application. My app use a `MainActivity`, a `NavigationDrawer` and `Fragments`. The fragment which display the calendar is called `MonthCalendar`.

A `GridView` is used to display the calendar.
My adapter is based on [droidwalk implementation](http://droidwalk.blogspot.fr/2012/11/android-calendar-sample.html).

My aim is to display, for each day a ImageView and a TextBox (day number). I fetch day data from a Web Service and store these data on a SQLite database.

**MonthFragment.java**

```
public class MonthFragment extends BaseFragment {

    public GridView gridview;
    public GregorianCalendar month, itemmonth;
    public CalendarAdapter adapter;
    public Handler handler;
    private DayRepository dayRepository;
    private List<Day> days;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_month, null);

        Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
        month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

        // Prepare the DB repository
        this.dayRepository = new DayRepository();
        ...
        adapter = new CalendarAdapter(view.getContext(), month);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView_month);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Handler
        days = new ArrayList<Day>();
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater);

        // Click event next/prev button call refreshCalendar()

        ...
        return view;
    }
    ...
    public void refreshCalendar() {
        TextView title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title);

        gridview.invalidateViews();
        adapter.refreshDays();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater);

        String monthTitle = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month);
        title.setText(monthTitle.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + monthTitle.substring(1));
    }

    public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            days.clear();

            // Fetch data from SQLlite DB
            days = dayRepository.getByMonth(month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)+1, month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));

            adapter.setDays(days);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

}
```

**CalendarAdapter.java**

```
public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Calendar month;

    public GregorianCalendar pmonth;
    public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
    private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;

    private int firstDay;
    private int maxWeeknumber;
    private int maxP;
    private int calMaxP;
    private int lastWeekDay;
    private int leftDays;
    private int mnthlength;
    private String itemvalue, curentDateString;
    private DateFormat df;

    public static List<String> dayString;
    private View previousView;

    private List<Day> days;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context c, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar) {
        CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<String>();
        month = monthCalendar;
        selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
        mContext = c;
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        this.days = new ArrayList<Day>();
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
        refreshDays();
    }

    public void setDays(List<Day> days) {
        this.days = days;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return dayString.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dayString.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        // Keeps reference to avoid future findViewById()
        CalendarViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);

            holder = new CalendarViewHolder();
            holder.dayImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_img);
            holder.dayDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_desc);
            holder.dayNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.rl_gridDay = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_gridDay);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CalendarViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
        String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");

        Log.d("Calendar", "===============> getView() call " + gridvalue);

        // Day is in current month?
        if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
            // Offdays (before month)
            holder.dayNumber.setClickable(false);
            holder.dayNumber.setFocusable(false);
            holder.rl_gridDay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
            // Offdays (after month)
            holder.dayNumber.setClickable(false);
            holder.dayNumber.setFocusable(false);
            holder.rl_gridDay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.dayNumber.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.rl_gridDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
            setSelected(view);
            previousView = view;
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }

        holder.dayNumber.setText(gridvalue);

        // START

        Day currentDay = null;
        if (date.length() > 0 && days != null) {
            for (Day object : days) {
                if (object.getMday() == Integer.parseInt(gridvalue)) {
                    currentDay = object;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            holder.dayImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.constellation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.dayDescription.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if (currentDay != null) {
            DayUtil dayUtil = new DayUtil(currentDay, mContext);

            holder.dayImg.setImageResource(dayUtil.getDrawableId());
            holder.dayDescription.setText(dayUtil.formatDesc());

            holder.dayImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.dayDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // END

        return view;
    }

    public View setSelected(View view) {
        if (previousView != null) {
            previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        previousView = view;
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cell_select);
        return view;
    }

    public void refreshDays() {
        days.clear();
        dayString.clear();

        pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
        // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
        firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        // finding number of weeks in current month.
        maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        if(maxWeeknumber >= 6) maxWeeknumber = 5;
        // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
        mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
        maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
        calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...

        pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
        pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

        /**
         * filling calendar gridview.
         */
        for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {
            itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
            pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
            dayString.add(itemvalue);
        }

    }

    private int getMaxP() {
        int maxP;
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1), month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }
        maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return maxP;
    }

    public static class CalendarViewHolder {
        public ImageView dayImg;
        public TextView dayDescription;
        public RelativeLayout rl_gridDay;
        public TextView dayNumber;
    }

}
```

**DayUtil.java**

```
public class DayUtil {
    private Day day;
    private Context context;
    ...
    /**
     * Return the day image picture ID
     * Dynamic loading of images R.Drawable depending on a day parameter
     */
    public int getDrawable() {
        ...
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

---

### First problem (performance issue)

The `GridView` class calls the `getView()` method of the adapter excessively (more or less 70 times). Main UI freezes few seconds and the loading is very slow.

I have tried to put operations betweek `// START` and `// END` line in a `AsyncTask`, but no improvements.

1. more than 70 getView() calls
2. GC_FOR_ALLOC

**Logcat**

```
01-25 17:07:56.132    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 29
01-25 17:07:56.140    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 29
01-25 17:07:56.140    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 30
01-25 17:07:56.144    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 31
01-25 17:07:56.148    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 1
01-25 17:07:56.152    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 2
01-25 17:07:56.152    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 3
01-25 17:07:56.156    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 4
01-25 17:07:56.160    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 5
01-25 17:07:56.160    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 6
01-25 17:07:56.168    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 7
01-25 17:07:56.172    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 8
01-25 17:07:56.176    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 9
01-25 17:07:56.180    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 10
01-25 17:07:56.184    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 11
01-25 17:07:56.188    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 12
01-25 17:07:56.188    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 13
01-25 17:07:56.192    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 14
01-25 17:07:56.196    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 15
01-25 17:07:56.200    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 16
01-25 17:07:56.204    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 17
01-25 17:07:56.204    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 18
01-25 17:07:56.208    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 19
01-25 17:07:56.208    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 20
01-25 17:07:56.212    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 21
01-25 17:07:56.216    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 22
01-25 17:07:56.216    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 23
01-25 17:07:56.220    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 24
01-25 17:07:56.224    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 25
01-25 17:07:56.228    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 26
01-25 17:07:56.232    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 27
01-25 17:07:56.232    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 28
01-25 17:07:56.236    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 29
01-25 17:07:56.240    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 30
01-25 17:07:56.240    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 31
01-25 17:07:56.244    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 1
01-25 17:07:56.332    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 29
01-25 17:07:56.340    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 29
01-25 17:07:56.344    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 30
01-25 17:07:56.356    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 31
01-25 17:07:56.356    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 1
01-25 17:07:56.360    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 2
01-25 17:07:56.360    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 3
01-25 17:07:56.364    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 4
01-25 17:07:56.372    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 416K, 4% free 16135K/16752K, paused 8ms, total 9ms
01-25 17:07:56.416    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 5
01-25 17:07:56.452    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4955K, 31% free 12739K/18312K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
01-25 17:07:56.464    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 6
01-25 17:07:56.492    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 7
01-25 17:07:56.520    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 8
01-25 17:07:56.528    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 21% free 14473K/18312K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
01-25 17:07:56.556    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 9
01-25 17:07:56.584    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 10
01-25 17:07:56.596    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 13% free 16029K/18312K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
01-25 17:07:56.628    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 11
01-25 17:07:56.664    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 12
01-25 17:07:56.672    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 4% free 17585K/18312K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
01-25 17:07:56.704    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 13
01-25 17:07:56.712    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 18363K/19092K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
01-25 17:07:56.744    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 14
01-25 17:07:56.752    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 19141K/19872K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
01-25 17:07:56.784    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 15
01-25 17:07:56.788    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 19919K/20652K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
01-25 17:07:56.820    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 16
01-25 17:07:56.820    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 17
01-25 17:07:56.832    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 4% free 20698K/21432K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
01-25 17:07:56.864    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 18
01-25 17:07:56.872    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 21476K/22212K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
01-25 17:07:56.904    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 19
01-25 17:07:56.912    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 22254K/22992K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
01-25 17:07:56.940    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 20
01-25 17:07:56.948    3243-3243/com.example.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 23032K/23772K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
01-25 17:07:56.980    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 21
01-25 17:07:57.024    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 22
01-25 17:07:57.068    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 23
01-25 17:07:57.104    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 24
01-25 17:07:57.140    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 25
01-25 17:07:57.140    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 26
01-25 17:07:57.180    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 27
01-25 17:07:57.212    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 28
01-25 17:07:57.212    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 29
01-25 17:07:57.212    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 30
01-25 17:07:57.216    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 31
01-25 17:07:57.216    3243-3243/com.example.android D/Calendar﹕ ===============> getView() call 1
```

### Some tries

- Set a fix GridView layout_height change nothing
- Set `scrollingCache="false"` change nothing [(see idea here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7897741/1123127)
- [Deep layout problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53733)?

Am I doing something wrong?
Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I notice in your `getView()` you have a for loop over `days` to find the proper `Day`. If you can find some way to access the `Day` directly, it might increase performance.

Comment: Also, there's nothing strange about more `getView` calls than you were expecting. `AdapterView`s like `ListView` and `GridView` may do this for measuring purposes.

Comment: What's about the `GC_FOR_ALLOC`? My GridView is so slow.

Comment: You should try using some profiling tools to actually analyze what takes the most time to do and what things are being allocated (because you are running low enough on memory that GC kicks in). Look at some of the tools here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html