# Lots of GC when scrolling ListView (with holder pattern)

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-listview

It's a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977718/lots-of-garbage-collection-in-a-listview), but the solution doesn't work.

The problem is that the scrolling of `ListView` is very sluggish which is because of lots and lots of GCs. I use holder pattern (view caching) as you can see in the code below:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.eventrow, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventTitle);
        holder.place = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventPlace);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
        // and the ImageView.
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
    holder.title.setText(((EventItem) getItem(position)).getTitle());
    holder.place.setText(((EventItem) getItem(position)).getPlace_name());

    return convertView;
}
```

I removed `cacheColorHint` and custom selectors from my listview and from rows:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

This is how the log looks like:

```
08-20 19:36:24.286: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 364K, 46% free 3944K/7239K, external 1196K/1445K, paused 54ms
08-20 19:36:24.356: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 228K, 49% free 3716K/7239K, external 1721K/1970K, paused 52ms
08-20 19:36:24.456: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 50ms
08-20 19:36:24.546: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 43ms
08-20 19:36:24.636: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 44ms
08-20 19:36:24.696: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 50ms
08-20 19:36:24.766: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 46ms
08-20 19:36:24.846: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 46ms
08-20 19:36:24.906: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 46ms
08-20 19:36:24.986: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 46ms
08-20 19:36:25.056: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 47ms
08-20 19:36:25.136: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 46ms
08-20 19:36:25.196: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 46ms
08-20 19:36:25.296: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 48ms
08-20 19:36:25.356: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3726K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 43ms
08-20 19:36:34.596: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 7K, 49% free 3740K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 51ms
08-20 19:36:34.656: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 49% free 3739K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 50ms
08-20 19:36:34.746: D/dalvikvm(12036): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3739K/7239K, external 2214K/2463K, paused 50ms
```

**EDIT:**
It seems that the problem appears (almost) only when the `ListFragment` is first inflated. For the first scroll down and then up. After that the GCs are not so often. But sometimes the GCs appear everytime I scroll. I can see no regularity here.
**PLUS** I can see the problem on HTC Desire (2.3.7 MIUI) but not on Sasmung Galaxy ACE (2.1). It only gets more confusing...

**Not so satisfying solution:**
When I use

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
android:animationCache="false"
```

in my listview it seems ok. But the docs say it should be exactly otherwise if I understand well, so I'm a little bit confused.

**Where do I make mistake? What to do to have a smooth scrolling listview? Or would disabling `scrollingCache` have some negative effect which I can't see now?**

Comment: Can you justify your use of caching `TextViews`, when the `static ViewHolder` already keeps that `TextView` in RAM?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I use the `ViewHolder` pattern described e.g. here: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/. Its very sense is caching `TextViews` and not inflating them on every `getView()`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Replace `getTitle()` and `getPlace_name()` with static strings. If your problem goes away, your issue lies in those methods.

Comment: Already tried (even removing those lines at all), forgot to mention, but thanks

Comment: Can't you use traceview to see what is happening when you scroll?

Comment: Are you sure that your views are  reused as convertViews and not created evry time anew?

Comment: aueselen - to be honest I didn't try using traceview for this. Will give it a shot. @Konstantin - I'm pretty sure. I mean, the convertView code seems ok to me, plus the "Not so satisfying solution" seems to work even if the ConvertView works wrong... So I don;t think it's the problem

Comment: If you are using fragments, sometimes you end up with overlapping views  and scrolling the top view will cause many views below to be invalidated. The problem is 99% not in your ListView.

Comment: is this happening just on HTC? I thing HTC-SENSE has serious memory problems. I heard about phones re-booting because HTC-SENSE was taking up all memory...

Answer (score 3):

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

Is the solution.

The docs say:

> When set to true, the list uses a drawing cache during scrolling. This
>   makes the rendering faster but uses more memory.

Now this does not give us any hint about the implementation details. I have an idea without investing hours of code analyzes.
For caching purposes, like Google recommends in their own documents, they use WeakReferences or WeakHashMaps. But it looks like the Dalvik VM is a bit too eager to kill off these References and causes them to be rebuild every time. This explains the huge GC activity and the sluggish user experience.

Links:
Blog about useless WeakReferences due to bug: http://chriswstewart.com/post/14199645893/improving-the-android-listview
Dalvik VM bug discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/66uw2t84rME

Comment: According to your theory (which is indeed interesting), scrollingCache is completely useless the way it's implemented by google. Would like to see system developers comment this...

Comment: While the problem with too early GC on WeakReferences/WeakHashMaps has already been noticed back to 2009 it might have turned into a serious problem in conjunction with ListViews when concurrent GC got introduced with Android 2.3. This would explain why the Android 2.1 device does not suffer from these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a background and/or a windowBackground for whatever is behind the ListView, I have seen this cause issues like this before.

Comment: The listview and fragment in which it's placed don't have backgrounds. It's a viewpager, and you can see through it. The closest background is that of an activity holding the viewpager. Can you elaborate?

Comment: As long as their is some kind of background or opaque view/drawable behind the ListView then my particular bug (that sounds just like yours) is fixed.

Comment: It won't help me (it would ruin my design), but is interesting. And you'll probably help google wanderers;) I'll try to investigate it, though... The problem is, that it started to work quite well now, without me doing anything (3 GC, one concurrent and two external_alloc at the start of scrolling and then it's smooth) so I don't really know how to check it. It's just too strange:P

Comment: If you are trying to use a semi-transparent ListView without anything between you and the defining Window then you are going to end up with performance problems.

Comment: Well not necessarily. I had problem on 2.3.7 HTC Desire, but it run smooth on a slower Samsung ACE. With newer phones (ICS) the performance was great. It looks like some king of GC problem rather than processor-heavy design

Answer (score -1):

try

```
listView.setCacheColorHint(0);

         &
protected void onDestroy() {
        System.gc();

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: I tried both using cacheColorHint and not, it doesn't change anything. And calling gc onDestroy won't help because the problem appears before onDestroy. But thanks for your input