# AChartEngine always GC

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine to draw a dynamic graph.But I found that the phone could not show the chart view and logcat just kept outputing GC info. My TestData.SENSOR_HISTORY_DATA only had 8 pairs of value-time. Anyone knows how to solve this? The ACE version is 1.0.

I got a graphicView from ChartFactory, then added it into my own linearlayout.

Here is my code：

```
public class HistoryDataChartDisp extends Activity {

    private XYSeries series;
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset;
    private GraphicalView chart;
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;
    private HistoryDataParser histDataParser = new HistoryDataParser();
    private LinearLayout layout;
    private List<String> histValueList;
    private List<String> histTimeList;
    private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history_data_chart_layout);
        ini();
        updateChart();
    }

    private void ini() 
    {
        layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.history_data_chart_linearLayout);

        series = new XYSeries("Title");

        mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        renderer = buildRenderer(Color.GREEN, PointStyle.POINT, true);

        setBasicChartSettings(renderer);

        mDataset.addSeries(series);
        //get the chart
        chart = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(getApplicationContext(), mDataset, renderer, 0.5f);

        layout.addView(chart, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));//将图表添加到布局中去
    }


    protected void setBasicChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer basicRenderer) 
    {
        basicRenderer.setAxesColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mirror));
        basicRenderer.setLabelsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mirror));
        basicRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        basicRenderer.setXLabels(5);
        basicRenderer.setYLabels(10);
        basicRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        basicRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        basicRenderer.setGridColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgray));

        basicRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{0,0,10,0});
        basicRenderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ivory));

        basicRenderer.setPointSize(1);
        basicRenderer.setShowLegend(false);

        basicRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);
        basicRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);

    }
    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildRenderer(int color, PointStyle style, boolean fill) 
    {       
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(color);
        r.setPointStyle(style);
        r.setFillPoints(fill);
        r.setLineWidth(2);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

        return renderer;
    }

    public void updateChart() {
        //For test
        //TestData.SENSOR_HISTORY_DATA is a String like this:value1,time1;value2,time2;...
        //
        updateData(TestData.SENSOR_HISTORY_DATA);
        chart.invalidate();
    }


    private void updateData(String response) 
    {
        histDataParser.parse(response);
        histValueList = histDataParser.getHistValueList();//get all values String
        histTimeList = histDataParser.getHistTimeList();//get all time String in same order with histValueList

        mDataset.removeSeries(series);

        series.clear();

        double x=0,y=0;

        int listSize = histTimeList.size();

        if(listSize<1)
        {
            series.add(0, 0);
        }
        else 
        {
            for (int i = listSize - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) 
            {
                try
                {
                    x = formatter.parse(histTimeList.get(i)).getTime();
                    y = Float.parseFloat(histValueList.get(i));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    x = 0;y = 0;
                }finally{
                    series.add(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
        mDataset.addSeries(series);
    }
}
```

Here's the logcat info.

```
    .
    .
    .
    05-19 14:07:35.269: D/dalvikvm(26285): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 21755 objects / 524280 bytes in 35ms
    05-19 14:07:35.359: D/dalvikvm(26285): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 21755 objects / 524280 bytes in 33ms
    05-19 14:07:35.449: D/dalvikvm(26285): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 21755 objects / 524280 bytes in 33ms
    .
    .
    .
    (keep outputing)
```

Also, i got this:[Lots of garbage collection in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977718/lots-of-garbage-collection-in-a-listview). The cause of that problem is android:cacheColorHint="#00000000". So i think if there's something i can do to reduce GC action.

Comment: What actions do you do on the chart when you see the GC messages? What version of ACE are you using?

Comment: I do nothing. The chart view cannot be shown. And i use ACE 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it - GC is simply the Android Garbage Collecting system. It's always going to be running in the background on every device.  More than likely, GC is simply outputting
what memory is available and what it has collected.

Comment: The problem is the chart cannot be shown. I have added some details about this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Its  my runnig code please check it.

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

```
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
private final XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = getDemoDataset();
private final XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = getDemoRenderer();
private GraphicalView mChartView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setRendererStyling();
    if (mChartView == null) {
        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset,
                mRenderer);
        // mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
        layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    } else
        mChartView.repaint();
}

private void setRendererStyling() {
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(10);
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.RED);
}

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset() {
    // double[] seriesFirstY = { 20, -20, 67, 180, -45, 24, 99, -34, -8 };
    final double[] seriesSecondY = { 10, 80, -40, -20, 135, 24, 199, -34, 80, 23,
            45, 34, 232, 234, 234, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 45, 45, 4, 534, 3, 4, 54,
            44, 54, 343, 34, 234, 3, 4, 4, 3, 645, 654, 34, 45, 34, 3, 34,
            34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 3, 4, 34, 4, 34, 34, 34, 34, 43, 34,
            34, 10, 80, -40, -20, 135, 24, 199, -34, 80, 23, 45, 34, 232,
            234, 234, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 45, 45, 4, 534, 3, 4, 54, 44, 54, 343,
            34, 234, 3, 4, 4, 3, 645, 654, 34, 45, 34, 3, 34, 34, 34, 34,
            34, 34, 34, 3, 4, 34, 4, 34, 34, 34, 34, 43, 34, 34, 34, 43,
            34, 34, 10, 80, -40, -20, 135, 24, 199, -34, 80, 23, 45, 34,
            232, 234, 234, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 45, 45, 4, 534, 3, 4, 54, 44, 54,
            343, 34, 234, 3, 4, 4, 3, 645, 654, 34, 45, 34, 3, 34, 34, 34,
            34, 34, 34, 34, 3, 4, 34, 4, 34, 34, 34, 34, 43, 34, 34, 34,
            43, 34, 34, 10, 80, -40, -20, 135, 24, 199, -34, 80, 23, 45,

            34, 43, 34, 34, 34, 43, 34, 34, 10, 80, -40, -20, 135, 24, 199,
            -34, 80, 23, 45, 34, 232, 234, 234, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 45, 45, 4,
            534, 3, 4, 54, 44, 54, 343, 34, 234, 3, 4, 4, 3, 645, 654, 34,
            45, 34, 3, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 3, 4, 34, 4, 34, 34, 34,
            34, 43, 34, 34, 34, 43, 34, 34, 10, 80, -40, -20, 135, 24, 199,
            -34, 80, 23, 45, 34, 232, 234, 234, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 45, 45, 4,
            534, 3, 4, 54, 44, 54, 343, 34, 234, 3, 4, 4, 3, 645, 654, 34,
            45, 34, 3, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 3, 4, 34, 4, 34, 34, 34,
            34, 43, 34, 34 };

    final XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    final XYSeries secondSeries = new XYSeries("Graph");
    for (int j = 0; j < seriesSecondY.length; j++)
        secondSeries.add(j, seriesSecondY[j]);
    dataset.addSeries(secondSeries);
    return dataset;
}

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getDemoRenderer() {
    final XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    final XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.POINT);
    r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    return renderer;
}
```

}

Comment: Those GC messages simply state that the Garbage Collector freed or tried to free some memory.   Evidently, you're using too much memory for the system to continue with the activity.  You might use MAT (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) to help determine where the memory is being consumed